# Preciso colocar os arquivos ocultos do projeto do Eclipse no repositório?

Tags: git, eclipse, github

Gostaria de saber primeiramente se estes da imagem arquivos ocultos (.algumacoisa) precisam ir pro repositório, uma vez que trabalho no mesmo projeto em mais de um computador.
Minha outra pergunta é se tem como não exibir estes arquivos no eclipse. Obrigado pela atenção.

[image: Uma captura de tela mostrando os arquivos do projeto do eclipse, como vistos no painel lateral. Há alguns arquivos começados em ponto, tais como .classpath, .project]

Answer (score 1):

Esses arquivos contém configurações como:

- informações sobre o repositório;
- informações sobre o projeto do Eclipse;
- configurações do Eclipse específicas do projeto;
- configurações usadas por diversas ferramentas;
- configurações do usuário.

Repositórios compartilhados por uma equipe normalmente possuem apenas arquivos que são úteis para toda a equipe ou várias pessoas dela. A decisão de versionar ou não esses arquivos, portanto, deve considerar evitar arquivos que contenham informações referentes ao ambiente do desenvolvedor (caminhos absolutos de diretórios, nomes de usuário, etc.), configurações de ferramentas opcionais ou preferências do usuário, a menos que essas informações sejam forçosamente padronizadas para toda a equipe. Geralmente, todos esses arquivos são arquivos texto, sendo possível inspecioná-los para verificar se há algumas dessas informações "pessoais" neles.

Também é considerada boa prática evitar arquivos que são gerados automaticamente ou que sejam frequentemente modificados desnecessariamente (por exemplo, uma ferramenta poderia inserir o *timestamp* de quando ela foi executada pela última vez).

A IDE muitas vezes é considerada uma escolha pessoal do desenvolvedor, portanto muitas equipes optam por não versionarem arquivos específicos de uma IDE (no caso, o Eclipse).

Não tenho experiência com Java para indicar exatamente quais arquivos contém o quê.